# Grain boundary contribution to energy density

Tags: material-science

I am trying to solve this practice problem and I'm having a tough time understanding what exactly is asked.

The density of dislocations in a material is 10^16/m2
a)  dislocation energy per unit length is Gb^2. Calculate energy density in a material with G=10^11 N/m^2 and b=0.2 nm

b)  Calculate the contribution of grain boundaries to the energy density ina material by assuming spherical grain of diameter d=10*10^-3 mm.  Energy density can be estimated from the surface to volune ration of the sphere and assigning half of the grain boundary energy to the surface of the sphere. Ygb(grain boundary energy) =1 J/m^2
c) Calculate the minimum grain size dmin after recrystalization of the material by equating contribution from dislocations before recrystalization with the contribution from the grain boundaries at grain size dmin.

The part a is pretty clear to me. I just multiplied the Gb^2 and dislocation density to get the energy density. 
I'm really clueless about part b and c.  I calculated the S/V ratio of sphere but I am not sure about what they mean by assign half the value to the surface or how to really go about getting the energy density from the S/V ratio. 
Part c seems to continue from part b so I'm super confused. If someone could guide me about how I should approach the problem, I'll be really grateful

Comment: I understand the the idea of half of the grain boundary surface is to avoid double count. Each surface belongs to 2 grains. Of course if all of them are spherical they don't fill the space, but it is just an exercise.

Comment: That seems reasonable but how do I get the energy density from the surface to volume ratio and what do they mean by assign half the energy to the surface in equation terms?

Comment: If you multiply Ygb by half the surface area of one grain, and divide by its volume, you get density of gb energy (energy / volume).

Comment: Oh that makes perfect sense. And I assume for part c I have to equate the value I got from part a with the formula I use in part b and calculate for d min? Is that correct?

Comment: As I understand, it is what part c says.